# problem shutting down

Tags: gnome, shutdown

Sometimes I have a problem shutting down.

I get a box saying "a program is still running - GNOME settings daemon" and this just stays there.

I can workround the problem by cancelling the box and doing shutdown again but it would be nice to resolve the problem another way.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will help you, it hasn't helped me yet but here is another answer I found on this problem.  It seems to me that it has something to do with graphics drivers as I am having the same issue of the proprietary driver not loading properly.  I am trying to resolve it now, I will keep you updated.

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2066978

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.